# How to modify the default Save / SaveAs path to our defined path on any browser’s Save/SaveAs pop up functionality?

Tags: java, apache-poi, struts-1

On a button click, I am downloading the excel sheet to a specific folder. The file is successfully saved.

Code is something like this :

```
Workbook wb = initWorksheet(form);
String exportFilePath =ResourceBundle.getBundle("Test").getString("Test_export_file_path"); //file path from properties file
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(exportFilePath + "/" + getNewFileName(fileName, exportFilePath));
wb.write(fileOut); // sheet is successfully downloaded at folder specified.
output = fileOut.toString();
fileOut.close();
```

(`HttpServletResponse`  response is send successfully and *Save/SaveAs* pop appears !)

But, when I click Save button on browser’s Save pop-up, excel file with same name and extension is downloaded in System’s Download folder (But this file is corrupted and we cannot open it)

So what I want is, even if I click Save in browser’s pop-up, I want the file to get download at the same path as mentioned in my properties file (here exportFilePath path)

Can anybody please help me in it !

Comment: How would you control what the Browser does via your code?

Comment: The browser controls browser behavior with regards to downloads.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the place where the user browser will save the downloads.